# Non-Noetherian 0-dimensional ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

I want to find a ring $R$ which satisfies

> $R$ is not Noether and $\operatorname{Spec}R$ is Hausdorff.

I found the latter condition is equivalent to R's Krull dimension is $0$.
So, I just need to find an example of Non-noether and $0$ dimensional ring.
Are there any good examples?
Thank you advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one takes $R=K[x_1,x_2,\ldots]/(x_1^2,x_2^2,\ldots)$ to be the polynomial ring over a field in infinitely many variables modulo the ideal $(x_1^2,x_2^2,\ldots)$, then $R$ is not noetherian and $\operatorname{Spec}R$ is a single point, in particular Hausforff.

Comment: Thank you! Why specR is a single point?

Comment: @川村はるか Because this is clearly a local ring. The nilradical $(x_1,\ldots)$ is clearly maximal.

Comment: Why specR is a local ring? If so, I can say specR is a singleton because R is PID.

Comment: I think specR is  local if R is algebraically closed. But if not so, I doubt specR is local.

Comment: The prime ideals of $R$ are the prime ideals of the polynomial ring containing the ideal $(x_1^2,x_2^2,...)$. But then, using the prime property, each such prime contains also the ideal $(x_1,x_2,...)$ which is maximal, hence we have equality, and $Spec(R)$ ist just the image of $(x_1,x_2,...)$ under the quotient map.